# Data not pulled from mysql at particular zoom level laone

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, geospatial

Between command not working correctly for geo coordinates

```
Select * from table_name where loc_lng BETWEEN $ln2 AND $ln1 AND loc_lat BETWEEN $la2 AND $la1
```

The code works perfectly fine when $ln2 is smaller than $ln1 and $la2 is smaller than $la1, but it dosent work when the values $ln1 is greater than $ln2 and $la1 is greater than $la2.
The ln and la are geo coordinates so sometimes one will be bigger than the other.

Answer (score 0):

That's to be expected.  You need additional logic to define the `minLatitude`, `maxLatitude`, `minLongitude` and `maxLongitude` **BEFORE** you pass the values to the query.

Then your query can be

```
Select * from table_name where loc_lng BETWEEN $minLongitude AND $maxLongitude AND loc_lat BETWEEN $minLatitude AND $maxLatitude
```